# Using split in a dictionary?

Tags: python

how do I go from:

```
{' electronic equipment, petroleum, natural gas, wood, wood products, palm oil, rubber, textiles, chemicals'}
```

to

```
{'electronic equipment', 'petroleum', 'natural gas', 'wood', 'wood products', 'palm oil', 'rubber', 'textiles', 'chemicals'}
```

Comment: That is a set literal in Python 2.7 or greater.

Comment: What you are showing there are `set`s, not `dict`s. If you want a `set` from a split string, just do `set(source_string.split(","))`.

Comment: I've tried but I get AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'.

Answer (score 1):

The first item is a **`set`** composed of single string not a dictionary. You can clean it up like this:

```
s = {' electronic equipment, petroleum, natural gas, wood, wood products, palm oil, rubber, textiles, chemicals'}
s = set( x.strip() for x in s.pop().split(',') )
```

The result will be a another `set` with multiple string members:

```
{'rubber', 'natural gas', 'petroleum', 'electronic equipment', 'wood products', 'chemicals', 'wood', 'palm oil', 'textiles'}
```

Answer (score 0):

that isn't a dictionary, it's a set. May be you should use a string:

```
In [16]: strs=' electronic equipment, petroleum, natural gas, wood, wood products, palm oil, rubber, textiles, chemicals'

In [17]: strs.split(",")
Out[17]: 
[' electronic equipment',
 ' petroleum',
 ' natural gas',
 ' wood',
 ' wood products',
 ' palm oil',
 ' rubber',
 ' textiles',
 ' chemicals']
```

or if you want to work on that set only, then try something like this. But you may not get ordered items this way:

```
In [25]: s={' electronic equipment, petroleum, natural gas, wood, wood products, palm oil, rubber, textiles, chemicals'}

In [26]: {y for x in s for y in x.split(",")}
Out[26]: 
set([' natural gas',
     ' chemicals',
     ' petroleum',
     ' rubber',
     ' wood',
     ' wood products',
     ' palm oil',
     ' electronic equipment',
     ' textiles'])
```

or as @Jon Clements suggested you can try something like:

```
In [43]: next(iter(s)).split(",")
Out[43]: 
[' electronic equipment',
 ' petroleum',
 ' natural gas',
 ' wood',
 ' wood products',
 ' palm oil',
 ' rubber',
 ' textiles',
 ' chemicals']
```

Comment: Or, `next(iter(s)).split(',')` possibly

Comment: @JonClements yes why not, nice alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
>>> s = {'hello,world'}
>>> set(s.pop().split(','))
set(['world', 'hello'])
```

But as you may have noticed it won't be sorted (order isn't guaranteed).